# Simultaneous calls block server

Tags: java, spring-boot, reactive-programming, spring-webflux, project-reactor

We have a service that is slow to respond for an average of 2 seconds whatever payload we send. We are batching multiple requests to save some bandwidth and don't choke that service.

I have this client around `WebClient` to collect and execute requests.

```
public class MyClient {
    private final WebClient client;
    private final Sinks.Many<String> requestSink;
    private final Flux<Map.Entry<String, TrackStatus>> output;

    public MyClient(URI uri, int queueSize, Duration timeout) {
        this.client = WebClient.create(uri.toString());
        this.requestSink = Sinks.many().multicast().onBackpressureBuffer(100, false);
        this.output = this.requestSink.asFlux().bufferTimeout(queueSize, timeout)
                .publishOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic())
                .flatMap(orderNumbers -> this.client.get()
                        .uri(uriBuilder -> uriBuilder
                                .path("/orders")
                                .queryParam("q", orderNumbers)
                                .build())
                        .retrieve()
                        .bodyToMono(Response.class)
                        .publishOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic())
                        .timeout(Duration.ofSeconds(3))
                        .onErrorReturn(this.createEmptyResponse(orderNumbers)))
                .flatMap(shipmentsResponse -> Flux.fromIterable(shipmentsResponse.getStatuses().entrySet()));
    }

    private Response createEmptyResponse(List<String> orderNumbers) {
        var response = new Response();

        for (String orderNumber : orderNumbers) {
            response.addStatus(orderNumber, null);
        }

        return response;
    }

    public void addOrderNumber(String orderNumber) {
        var emitResult = this.requestSink.tryEmitNext(orderNumber);

        while (emitResult.isFailure()) {
            emitResult = this.requestSink.tryEmitNext(orderNumber);
        }
    }

    public Flux<Map.Entry<String, TrackStatus>> output() {
        return this.output;
    }
}

public class Response {
    private Map<String, Status> statuses = new HashMap<>();

    @JsonAnySetter
    public void addStatus(String orderNumber, Status status) {
        this.statuses.put(orderNumber, status);
    }

    @JsonAnyGetter
    public Map<String, Status> getStatuses() {
        return this.statuses;
    }
}

public enum Status {
    NEW,
    IN_TRANSIT,
    DELIVERED;
}
```

I am using this client in business service.

```
public class Service  {

    private final MyClient client;

    public Service(MyClient client) {
        this.client = client;
    }

    public Mono<Response> getStatus(Set<String> orderNumbers) {
        var statuses = this.client.output()
                .filter(e -> orderNumbers.contains(e.getKey()))
                .take(orderNumbers.size())
                .collect(this.nullSafeCollector());

        Flux.fromIterable(orderNumbers)
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic())
                .subscribe(this.client::addOrderNumber);

        return statuses
                .publishOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic())
                .map(t -> new Response(t));
    }

    private <K, V> Collector<Map.Entry<K, V>, Map<K, V>, Map<K, V>> nullSafeCollector() {
        return Collector.of(HashMap::new
                , (m, entry) -> m.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue())
                , (m1, m2) -> {
                    m1.putAll(m2);
                    return m1;
                }
                , Collector.Characteristics.UNORDERED);
    }
}

public final class Response {
    private final Map<String, Status> statuses;

    public GetAggregationResponse(Map<String, Status> statuses) {
        this.statuses = statuses;
    }

    public Map<String, Status> getStatuses() {
        return this.statuses;
    }
}
```

This business service is used from the following controller.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/collect", produces = APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public class Controller {

    private final Service service;

    public Controller(Service service) {
        this.service = service;
    }

    @GetMapping()
    @ResponseStatus(value = OK)
    private Mono<Response> getAggregation(@RequestParam(name = "order") Set<String> orderNumbers) {
        return this.service.getStatus(orderNumbers);
    }
}
```

This is working without any problem for a single request. But when I make simultaneous multiple calls to the service. Service hangs and returns no response to all of the callers.

I ran the application with [BlockHound](https://github.com/reactor/BlockHound) to see what is blocking the server but there is no output from it. How I can understand what is causing hanging?

I am using Java 15 with Spring Boot 2.4.0 which has Reactor 3.4.0.

Comment: Did you check with `Request` scope of your Service class? Default, it is `Singleton`.

Comment: @user370305 `Request` scope isn't supported in spring-webflux.